# Mock for Stripe error in Jasmine tests?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, stripe-payments

The following code is raising an error in the test environment because `StripeCheckout` is not defined:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_...',
  image: '/images/marketplace.png',
  token: function(token) {
    process(token);
  }
});
```

How to create a Stripe Mock?

I thought something like this might work:

```
function StripeMock(){
}

StripeMock.prototype.configure = function( config ){
  console.log('configure');
}

var StripeCheckout = new StripeMock();
```

But I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a object`.

So, what is a good way to mock the StripeCheckout object?

Comment: Can you show more code here since this isn't making sense? Please include the entire test file.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use Spies?

http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html

http://tobyho.com/2011/12/15/jasmine-spy-cheatsheet/

Something like:

```
StripeCheckout = {
    configure: jasmine.createSpy("configure() spy");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Spies would probably be a better idea, but got it working with JS functions:

```
function StripeMock(){
}

StripeMock.prototype.configure = function( config ){
  console.log('Stripe Mock init.');
  return new Handler();
}

function Handler(){
}
Handler.prototype.open = function(params){
  console.log('Stripe Mock handler opened.')
}
Handler.prototype.close = function(){
}

var StripeCheckout = new StripeMock();
```

Comment: This is what I had to resort to also, because I could not get spies to work.