# mock StripeCheckout in Jasmine test

Tags: jasmine, stripe-payments, karma-jasmine

I am writing Jasmine tests for my Javascript application. A major time-sink has been testing my code which depends on StripeCheckout. Stripe does not want you to use it offline. I realized I should mock the service, but that has not been easy in Jasmine.

How can I mock "custom" (instead of "simple") usage of [StripeCheckout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout)?

I tried to use [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>), like so,

```
var StripeCheckout = jasmine.createSpyObj('StripeCheckout', ['configure']);
```

But I think the created object needs to attach to the global object (window).

- So, I can [add an object to the global
  object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29803868/1740008). This worked,
  but it feels lame.
- Another option could be to tell
  [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/index.html) to load the
  page over the network. This worked for me, but it seems lame to make
  a network request for tests.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have figured this out yet but an easy way to do this would be to just create a simple mocked implementation for StripeCheckout. Something like this should work.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module(function($provide) {
        $provide.factory('StripeCheckout', function() {
            //your mocked custom implementation goes here

            configure: function() {
                //do something   
            }
        }
    }

    inject(function($injector) {
        StripeCheckoutMock = $injector.get('StripeCheckout');
    }
)
```

This way you are not making a request in order to run your tests. The test will just use the mocked service that you have set up.

Comment: I have not figured this out. I have used a few less-than-ideal solutions. Interesting idea - add an Angular service in the tests. I guess I should wrap `window.StripeCheckout` and make my angular code use DI for the StripeCheckout symbol. I am using Angular but I am looking a solution that does not require Angular.